# Sum cells above iteratively

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have the linear distance between points on a map, and I would like to use this information in my graphs in a way that would line up with the map. I have the lat long data and converted it to distance in meters using the `measurements` package in R, but my professor said he wants the graphs to show the actual distance between the samples.

Here's some mock data, with Sum being the desired output:

```
Sample  Distance  Sum
  1        0       0
  2        0.2    0.2
  3        0.3    0.5
  4        0.6    1.1
```

From this I could use Sum as an x axis to plot the relative distance for our class data.

I'm not sure if there's a simple way to do this, or if I need to make a loop or something. How would any of you approach this? Thanks!

Comment: check out the `cumsum` function